# when to use themes.color in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack compose.
I'm studying about themes, and the color in themes.
Searching for the usage of colors attribute(primary, onPrimary, background, onBackground),
I wondered why there are many attributes, and when to use this attrs.
I found the guide in accompanist docs

[https://google.github.io/accompanist/appcompat-theme](https://google.github.io/accompanist/appcompat-theme/)

but couldn't understand between the meaning and the real usage.

For example the Button.kt in compose, the button functions have all different value at same parameter attribute.

```
//Button.kt - 402 line
@Composable
fun buttonColors(
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    disabledBackgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.12f)
        .compositeOver(MaterialTheme.colors.surface),
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        .copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
): ButtonColors = DefaultButtonColors(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    contentColor = contentColor,
    disabledBackgroundColor = disabledBackgroundColor,
    disabledContentColor = disabledContentColor
)

//Button.kt - 426 line
@Composable
fun outlinedButtonColors(
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        .copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
): ButtonColors = DefaultButtonColors(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    contentColor = contentColor,
    disabledBackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    disabledContentColor = disabledContentColor
)

//Button.kt - 446 line
@Composable
fun textButtonColors(
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    disabledContentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        .copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled)
): ButtonColors = DefaultButtonColors(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    contentColor = contentColor,
    disabledBackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    disabledContentColor = disabledContentColor
)
```

the backgroundColor parameters are all different by function.
thinking about this case, I don't understand using the themes.colors is the good way.
when should I use the themes.colors?
Or should I match the primary, primaryVariant, secondary, secondaryVariant... in the same?

Comment: What you are using is a set of components from `compose.material` library that follow Material Design guidelines. They have a comprehensive guide on all these.
[Material Design](https://material.io/)

Comment: that's not what I want to get. My question is that why buttonColors's backgroundColor is MaterialTheme.colors.primary and other buttons backgroundColors  are different each other

Comment: Material design guidelines have that documented please check it before you complain. Material has colors such as primary and onPrimary for content on top of the primary etc.